# Exibir mais de uma informação na mesma tabela com PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Gostaria de exibir na tabela as informações do aluno cadastrado e também dos cursos que ele está inscrito.

### **Resultado final que gostaria que fosse exibido:**

```
Nome Aluno | Telefone Aluno | Cursos
---------------------------------------------------
João       | 12988776655    | Algoritmos
Maria      | 12988776655    | Algortimos, IA, UX
Carlos     | 12988776655    | UX, IA
```

Tenho Três Tabelas: Aluno, Cursos e Inscrição.

**Tabela Aluno:**
Cadastro as informações dos alunos! A estrutura é:

```
aluno_id | aluno_nome | aluno_telefone
----------------------------------------
1        | João       | 12988776655
2        | Maria      | 12988776655
3        | Carlos     | 12988776655
```

**Tabela Cursos:**
Cadastro as informações do curso! A estrutura é:

```
curso_id | curso_nome | curso_dataInicio | curso_dataFim
-------------------------------------------------------
1        | Algoritmos | 12/01/2018       | 12/06/2018
2        | IA         | 12/01/2018       | 12/06/2018
3        | UX         | 12/01/2018       | 12/06/2018
```

**Tabela Inscrição:**
Aqui é onde faço a ligação dos cursos que o aluno está cadastrado, onde *inscricao_alunoID* e *inscricao_cursoID* são chaves estrangeiras vinculadas ao id tanto da tabela aluno quanto da tabela curso, então fica assim::

```
inscricao_aluno_curso_id | inscricao_alunoID | inscricao_cursoID
1                        | 1                 | 1
2                        | 2                 | 1
3                        | 2                 | 2
4                        | 2                 | 3
5                        | 3                 | 3
6                        | 3                 | 2
```

Dado as informações acima, eu gostaria de exibir os cursos do aluno na mesma célula na tabela! Para isto eu fiz este trecho de código para a exibição das informações:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome Aluno</th>
                <th>Nome Telefone</th>
                <th>Cursos</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    <?php while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $record['nome_aluno']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $record['telefone_aluno']; ?></td>
            <td><?php while($recordCurso = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCurso)){
                            if($recordCurso['inscricao_alunoID'] == $record['aluno_id']){
                                echo $recordCurso['nome_curso'].", ";
                            }
                       }
                  ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Onde, dentro do *while* ele passaria por cada índice do aluno e, se o índice atual fosse igual ao que está dentro do índice da minha segunda consulta, então exibiria o nome do curso!

As minhas consultas que estão armazenadas nas variáveis $result e $resultCurso são:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM aluno");

$resultCurso = mysqli_query(
    $con, " SELECT c.nome_curso, i.inscricao_alunoID
            FROM inscricao i
            INNER JOIN curso c ON i.inscricao_cursoID = c.curso_id "
);
```

Desta maneira que fiz aparece o resultado **certo apenas para o primeiro aluno!** Nos próximos alunos está ficando tudo branco!

**Obs.: Se existir outra maneira de fazer isso que desejo também estou aceitando sugestões melhores.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema esta no `while($recordCurso = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCurso))` pois o `resultset` `$resultCurso`, após terminar o primeiro aluno, estará no ultimo registro. Então quando chegar no segundo aluno, não tem como retornar o proximo (pois já está no fim).

Uma solução possivel é usar a função [mysqli_data_seek()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) para retornar para o inicio do resultset (posição 0). Isso permitirá que a sua estrutura funcione corretamente. Aplicando fica assim:

```
<?php while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $record['nome_aluno']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['telefone_aluno']; ?></td>
    <td><?php while($recordCurso = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCurso)){
               if($recordCurso['inscricao_alunoID'] == $record['aluno_id']){
                    echo $recordCurso['nome_curso'].", ";
               }
         }
         //logo após o while que lista os cursos, 
         //faça o curso voltar para o inicio do resultset
         mysqli_data_seek($resultCurso, 0);
         ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Uma solução mais completa seria usar a consulta apresentada na resposta do @WellingtonRogati, que é juntar as duas consultas que você faz em uma só. A consulta seria algo similar a isso:

```
SELECT * FROM aluno, curso, inscricao WHERE 
inscricao.inscricao_alunoID = aluno.aluno_id AND  
inscricao.inscricao_cursoID = curso.curso_id
```

Isso retornaria:

```
aluno_id | aluno_nome | aluno_telefone | curso_id | curso_nome | curso_dataInicio | curso_dataFim | inscricao_aluno_curso_id | inscricao_alunoID | inscricao_cursoID
```

A partir daqui você poderia montar um array (antes de montar a tabela em html), para organizar seus dados. O array deve ter essa estrutura:

```
[
    'aluno_id' => [
         'aluno' => [
             'aluno_nome' => 'valor', 'aluno_telefone' => 'valor'
         ], 
         'cursos' => [
             ['curso_id' => valor, 'curso_nome' => 'valor'],
             ['curso_id' => valor, 'curso_nome' => 'valor']
         ]
     ],
     'aluno_id' => [
         'aluno' => [
             'aluno_nome' => 'valor', 'aluno_telefone' => 'valor'
         ], 
         'cursos' => [
             ['curso_id' => valor, 'curso_nome' => 'valor'],
             ['curso_id' => valor, 'curso_nome' => 'valor']
         ]
     ]
]
```

para montar esse aray você pode fazer assim:

```
<?php
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM aluno, curso, inscricao WHERE 
inscricao.inscricao_alunoID = aluno.aluno_id AND  
inscricao.inscricao_cursoID = curso.curso_id');

$novoArray = [];

//a partir desse array (que tem varias repetições) criaremos o array    
//descrito acima. A estrutura de $novoArray segue a ideia de
// [conjuntos][2], onde não há elementos repetidos
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);){
    //a cada execução do while, se houver mais de uma tupla com 
    //informaçoes do aluno, a ultima sobrescrevera a anterior 
    $novoArray['aluno_id']['aluno'] = [
         'aluno_nome' => $linha['aluno_nome'],
         'aluno_telefone' => $linha['aluno_telefone'],
    ];
    //no caso dos cursos não haverá sobrescrita, pois são informações
    // distintas. Basicamente, para cada tupla que
    $novoArray['aluno_id']['cursos'][] = [
          'curso_id' => $linha['curso_id'],
          'curso_nome' => $linha['curso_nome']
    ]
}

// e imprima a tabela
foreach($novoArray as aluno){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $aluno['aluno']['aluno_nome']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aluno['aluno']['aluno_telefone']; ?></td>

        <td><?php 
        foreach($aluno['cursos'] as $curso){
            echo $curso['curso_nome'].", ";
        }
        ?>
        </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: A resposta do @WellingtonRogati foi muito completa, contudo a sua me preveniu de uma semana de pesquisa! Eu estou me aprofundando mais agora no PHP e MySQL e você ter apontado que o _resultset_ depois que percorrido ele não volta mais me deu um índico para entender mais sobre o que de fato é retornado numa MySQL e com o que trabalhamos no PHP. Você teria mais informações ou links para eu me aprofundar mais no assunto? Muito grato!

Comment: @WesleyRedfield As referencias de [mysqli](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp) e de [banco de dados](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) do W3C, são um bom começo, embora estejam em inglês.

Answer (score 1):

Wesley, reproduzi as tabelas que você mencionou no meu ambiente e com a query abaixo trago os registros da maneira que dá para mostrar via PHP como você quer :

SELECT * FROM aluno a, curso c, inscricao i
        WHERE i.inscricao_alunoID = a.aluno_id
          AND i.inscricao_cursoID = c.curso_id

[image: Resultado da query]

Agora para mostrar no PHP eu não como reproduzir aqui na minha máquina agora, mas posso lhe explicar como dá para fazer:

1 - Faz um loop como você fez com while mesmo, só que não imprime o registro no momento que que ele foi trazido da query.

2 - Acumule numa variável exemplo: $cursos .= " " . $record['curso_nome'];

3 - Verifique com "if" se o loop mudou de "aluno_id", se sim imprima na tela o resultado ou guarde em um array, depende de sua necessidade.

Resumindo, embora a query traga registros repetidos no caso da "Maria" o que importa em acumular é o nome do curso pois é a informação que varia, lembre que nesse acúmulo utilizamos concatenação.

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa manda aí.

Comment: Tentei fazer o que você disse e não consegui... Pode me mostrar aqui como seria isto no PHP? Por favor!

Principalmente a linha 3... Como seria isto no PHP?
De qualquer maneira Dei +1 voto pela resposta!

Comment: Wesley, valeu pelo voto, vou fazer um script aqui e edito a resposta e te viso. Abs

Answer (score 1):

É possível trazer o resultado como você quer, utilizando apenas a query do MySQL.

Você pode executar a seguinte query:

```
SELECT
  a.`nome` AS aluno_nome,
  a.`telefone` AS aluno_telefone,
  GROUP_CONCAT(c.`curso`) AS cursos
FROM
  `aluno` a
LEFT JOIN
  `aluno_has_cursos` ac ON(ac.aluno_id = a.id)
LEFT JOIN
  `cursos` c ON(ac.curso_id = c.id)
GROUP BY
  a.`nome`;
```

#### Explicando o código

> **GROUP_CONCAT** = Essa função retorna todos os valores concatenados através do GROUP BY. Caso não possua valor, retornará NULL
>
> **LEFT JOIN** = Vai mesclar o conteúdo das 3 tabelas
>
> **GROUP BY** = Vai agrupar os valores. Isso vai evitar de trazer vários "Maria" com informações iguais (só mudando o nome do curso).

Você pode ver o código funcionando no site **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/395344/1)**

O `GROUP_BY` ele não está relacionado com o `LEFT JOIN`, mas sim com o `GROUP BY`.

O `LEFT JOIN` ele vai mesclar o conteúdo de várias tabelas comparando os dados no `ON`, com isso você consegue retornar vários dados iguais com determinadas colunas diferentes.

Quando você utiliza o `GROUP BY` em uma coluna, você está informando para o `MySQL` agrupar todos os registros, daquela determinada coluna, que são iguais. Exemplo: se tiver dois "João" na coluna `nome`, ele vai agrupar todos os registros relacionados a "João" em uma linha só e vai manter apenas um deles a mostra, com o `GROUP_CONCAT` em uma coluna, eu informo para o `MySQL` capturar essas informações restantes, que não seria exibidas, e concatenar tudo em uma informação só.

> Explicação mais detalha sobre o uso do `(LEFT) JOIN` https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/99718

Comment: Perfeito! O seu código funciona e eu realmente não imaginei fazer apenas uma consulta e já retornar tudo. Mas confesso que não estou entendendo 100%. Tipo... Em qual momento que está relacionando o GROUP_CONTACT com o _LEFT JOIN `cursos` c ON(ac.curso_id = c.id)_ ?

Comment: @WesleyRedfield editei minha resposta com uma explicação.